# Mapnik image render not corresponding to generated tiles

Tags: style, scale, zoom, mapnik, rendering

I successfully manage to install a tile server using Mapnik following this tutorial: https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-ubuntu-22-04-lts/

The tiles are fine and look like the CartoCSS style defined. But when I am trying to generate a bigger image with node-mapnik in an upper resolution, the style seems to be the one at another zoom level (colors lighter or darker and roads fatter or thinner than expected).

Here is the code used:

```
var map = new mapnik.Map(width, height);
map.loadSync("style.xml");
map.zoomToBox([-962632.2111654571, 4534252.301069, 1483352.6939602145, 7958631.16824493]);
const buffer = map.renderSync({ format: 'jpeg', quality: 100 }, new mapnik.Image(width, height));
return buffer;
```

Size of the image and bounds of the map are correct, so what am I missing ? I tried to change the scale factor and the scale denominator, but it seems that I am not able to get the right combination. What formula should be used? Is there another alternative to generate such an image (using CartoCSS)?